# Windows Store submission: We don't allow the capability you've specified: ID_CAP_RINGTONE_ADD

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

> 2008: We don't allow the capability you've specified: ID_CAP_RINGTONE_ADD

I'm submitting a windows phone app (WP8 version) that uses SaveRingtoneTask, and in its WMAppManifest.xml I've specified ID_CAP_RINGTONE_ADD capability, however the error message above still showing

There's WP7.1 version of this app, which I add the assembly reference to this WP8 version, and the SaveRingtoneTask is code is stored in that assembly, does this affect the error above ?

AppPlatformVersion in WMAppManifest.xml already set to "8.0"

Comment: I removed the ID_CAP_RINGTONE_ADD capability from the WP8 app and successfully validated it. When testing the app on phone, the SaveRingtoneTask is working successfully. Not sure if the distributed xap will have problem in setting the ringtone or not

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating a Windows Phone 8 app? ID_CAP_RINGTONE_ADD is only available for Windows Phone 8 version.

[From this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/wpapps/en-US/df76d906-c898-4dc8-9692-5f2d45844cb2/2008-we-dont-allow-the-capability-youve-specified-idcapcamera)

Comment: yes, I'm creating a WP8 app, and as I said previously, I added the WP7 version assembly into this WP8 app. Not sure if that affect the validation process

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't you should upgrade the app to Windows Phone 8 by right-clicking the Windows Phone 7.1 project in Visual Studio 2012 and selecting Upgrade to Windows Phone 8. You’ll receive a prompt that cautions you that this upgrade can’t be undone and doesn’t update any referenced projects. You’ll want to make sure that your app is backed up before proceeding. You can also upgrade to Windows Phone 8 by selecting Project Properties, clicking on the Application page, selecting Windows Phone OS 8 from the dropdown list and saving your changes.

I recommend backing up your project before trying this because the changes are not reversible.
Thanks and hope this helps you.

Comment: actually I have done this, and this WP8 app is the result of above process. However some of the codes are duplicate for both versions, so I factor out reusable codes into the WP7 app, and include the WP7 assembly into my WP8 app. This includes the SaveRingtoneTask functionality. Is it I need to include ID_CAP_RINGTONE_ADD to the WP7 manifest xml too?